# Where's the Vaadin 7 demo code located?

Tags: gwt, vaadin

Where is the Vaadin demo code for http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler located?

What I specifically need to look at is the circular menu design and code. I hope this is something they have shared.

Comment: the source for the sampler got never released.  the reason then was "use of third party software".  i thought i read this in the forum, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the newest sampler has not been released, explained by Marko from the Vaadin team in this [forum post](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/335188/9833303). Shortly: it's not a great example on how to code an application on the code level, but more visual candy. The components code can be viewed separately from the UI, but unfortunately the menu is not published. Although it seems to be mostly CSS-transformations, so with a little debugging on the client side, you could be able to figure out enough just from the browser.